# Is the rotated DFT of an image really the same as the DFT of the image’s rotation?

Tags: visual-c++, fft

Or should I ask-  Does the rotation property for Fourier Transforms apply to discrete FFTs?
I've written a win32 console program using VS2015.
In my program I cache an array of 4 DFTs of rotations (0, 90, 180 & 270deg) of the user’s input image.
These 4 DFTs can occupy a lot of memory. 
I want to reduce the memory cost by computing the FT of a rotated image when required.
To reduce the time cost, I figure that it would be faster to rotate the FT of the input, than to compute the FT of the rotated image.

After much experimenting I cannot make this work. I would like to know why??

For instance, consider a 90deg rotation CCW, r90.
Why doesn’t, r90(FT(in)) = FT(r90(in)) ?

Example-  A 4px4p input image.

```
Input image,  'in' 
 23   87   90    3   
 39   51   56   95   
 12   84   47   61   
 71   18   11   96   

Fourier Transform of input,  FT_in = FT(in)  
 844,0   -59,15    -146,0   -59,-15   
 -1,-45  -66,16    109,19   2,138   
 -30,0   -145,-229  20,0    -145,229   
 -1,45   2,-138    109,-19  -66,-16   

Centered FT of input,  cDC_FT_In = FT(in)  
 20,0     -145,229  -30,0   -145,-229   
 109,-19  -66,-16   -1,45   2,-138   
 -146,0   -59,-15   844,0   -59,15   
 109,19   2,138     -1,-45  -66,16   

Rotated FT of input,  r90_FT_In = R90(FT(in))  
 -145,-229   2,-138   -59,15   -66,16   
 -30,0      -1,45     844,0    -1,-45   
 -145,229   -66,-16   -59,-15   2,138   
 20,0       109,-19   -146,0   109,19   

(A) Recentered Rotated FT of input, cDC_r90_FT_In = cDC(r90(FT(in)))  
 20,0      109,-19  -146,0   109,19   
 -145,-229 2,-138   -59,15   -66,16   
 -30,0     -1,45    844,0    -1,-45   
 -145,229  -66,-16  -59,-15   2,138   

Rotated input,  r90_in = r90(in)  
  3   95   61   96   
 90   56   47   11   
 87   51   84   18   
 23   39   12   71   

FT of rotated input, FT_r90_in = FT(r90(in))  
 844,0-1,-45   -30,0      -1,45   
 15,-59  -138,2   -229,-145  16,-66   
 146,0   -109,-19 -20,0      -109,19   
 15,59    16,66   -229,145   -138,-2   

(B) Centered FT of rotated input, cDC_r90_FT_In = cDC(FT(r90(in)))  
 -20,0      -109,19   146,0   -109,-19   
 -229,145   -138,-2   15,59   16,66   
 -30,0      -1,45     844,0   -1,-45   
 -229,-145   16,-66   15,-59  -138,2
```

Why are (A) the rotated FT of input,  and (B) the FT of rotated input, different?

Here's the simple test programme which produces the above print out.

```
// DFT Rotn.cpp : Tests the Rotation Property of Discrete Fourier Transforms.
// FFT() & FFT2D() are  modified code by Paul Bourke: http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/dft/
//
// Prints out to the console and debug output.
// To enable printing to debug output, uncomment lines below containing, 
// "// Uncomment to print to debug output" 

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
//#include <Windows.h> // Uncomment to print to debug output
using namespace std;    

const int inD = 4; // Input image W & H 

int FFT(int dir, int nn, double *x, double *y);
int FFT2D(double c[4][4][2],int inW,int inH,int dir);
void print2dArray(char str[100], int array[inD][inD]);
void printComplex2dArray(char str[100], double array[inD][inD][2]);
void cyclicShiftComplex2dArray(double inRA[inD][inD][2], double outRA[inD][inD][2], 
                               int xOff, int yOff);

int main() {    

   int in[inD][inD] = 
    { {23, 87, 90,  3},   
      {39, 51, 56, 95},
      {12, 84, 47, 61},
      {71, 18, 11, 96} };   
   print2dArray("\n\nInput image,  'in' ", in);

   // Create the Fourier Transform of the input.
   double FT_in[inD][inD][2];
   for(int y2=0;  y2<inD;  y2++)
      for(int x2=0;  x2<inD;  x2++){
         FT_in[y2][x2][0] = in[y2][x2];
         FT_in[y2][x2][1] = 0;
      }//for(x3)
   FFT2D(FT_in, inD, inD, 1);
   printComplex2dArray("\n\nFourier Transform of input,  FT_in = FT(in)", FT_in);

   // Center the DC point of the FT of the input.
   double cDC_FT_In[inD][inD][2];
   cyclicShiftComplex2dArray(FT_in, cDC_FT_In, inD/2, inD/2);
   printComplex2dArray("\n\nCentered FT of input,  cDC_FT_In = FT(in)", cDC_FT_In);

   // Create the rotated Fourier Transform of the input.
   double r90_FT_In[inD][inD][2];
   for(int y3=0;  y3<inD;  y3++){
      for(int x3=0;  x3<inD;  x3++){
         r90_FT_In[y3][x3][0] = cDC_FT_In[x3][inD-1 - y3][0]; // Real compt
         r90_FT_In[y3][x3][1] = cDC_FT_In[x3][inD-1 - y3][1]; // Imag compt
      }//for(x2)
   }//for(y2)
   printComplex2dArray("\n\nRotated FT of input,  r90_FT_In = R90(FT(in))", r90_FT_In);

   // Recenter the DC point of the rotated FT, using a cyclic shift.
   double cDC_r90_FT_In[inD][inD][2];
   cyclicShiftComplex2dArray(r90_FT_In, cDC_r90_FT_In, 0, 3);
   printComplex2dArray("\n\n(A) Recentered Rotated FT of input, cDC_r90_FT_In = cDC(r90(FT(in)))",
                       cDC_r90_FT_In);

   // Create the Input Rotated 90deg CCW.
   int r90_in[4][4];
   for(int y4=0;  y4<inD;  y4++)
      for(int x4=0;  x4<inD;  x4++)
         r90_in[y4][x4] = in[x4][inD-1 - y4];
   print2dArray("\n\nRotated input,  r90_in = r90(in)", r90_in);

   // Create the Fourier Transform of the rotated input.
   double FT_r90_in[inD][inD][2];
   for(int y5=0;  y5<inD;  y5++)
      for(int x5=0;  x5<inD;  x5++){
         FT_r90_in[y5][x5][0] = r90_in[y5][x5];
         FT_r90_in[y5][x5][1] = 0;
      }//for(x3)
   FFT2D(FT_r90_in, inD, inD, 1);
   printComplex2dArray("\n\nFT of rotated input, FT_r90_in = FT(r90(in))", FT_r90_in);
   cyclicShiftComplex2dArray(FT_r90_in, cDC_r90_FT_In, inD/2, inD/2);
   printComplex2dArray("\n\n(B) Centered FT of rotated input, cDC_r90_FT_In = cDC(FT(r90(in)))", cDC_r90_FT_In);

    return 0;

}//main()

/* This computes an in-place complex-to-complex FFT
   x and y are the real and imaginary arrays of 2^m points.
   dir =  1 gives forward transform   dir = -1 gives reverse transform. */
int FFT(int dir, int nn, double *x, double *y){
   long n, m, i, i1, j, k, i2, l, l1, l2;
   double c1, c2, tx, ty, t1, t2, u1, u2, z;

    // Calculate m where nn = 2^m
   for(n = 1, m  = 0; n < nn; n *= 2)  m++;
    // Do the bit reversal.
   i2 = nn >> 1;   j = 0;
   for (i=0; i<nn-1; i++) {
      if (i < j) {
         tx = x[i];         ty = y[i];
         x[i] = x[j];       y[i] = y[j];
         x[j] = tx;         y[j] = ty;
      }//if()
      k = i2;
      while (k <= j) { j -= k;   k >>= 1; }
      j += k;
   }//for(i)

    // Compute the FFT.
   c1 = -1.0;   c2 = 0.0;   l2 = 1;
   for (l=0; l<m; l++) {
      l1 = l2;    l2 <<= 1;    u1 = 1.0;     u2 = 0.0;
      for (j=0; j<l1; j++) {
         for (i=j; i<nn; i+=l2) {
            i1 = i + l1;
            t1 = u1 * x[i1]  -  u2 * y[i1];
            t2 = u1 * y[i1]  +  u2 * x[i1];
            x[i1] = x[i] - t1;      y[i1] = y[i] - t2;
            x[i] += t1;             y[i] += t2;
         }//for(i)
         z =  u1*c1 - u2*c2;    u2 = u1*c2 + u2*c1;    u1 = z;
      }//for(j)
      c2 = (double)sqrt((1.0 - c1) / 2.0);
      if (dir == 1)    
         c2 = -c2;
      c1 = (double)sqrt((1.0 + c1) / 2.0);
   }//for(l)

   return 1;
}//FFT()


int FFT2D(double c[4][4][2],int inW,int inH,int dir) {
   int i,j;
   double *real,*imag;

   /* Transform the rows */
   real = new double[inW];   imag = new double[inW];
   for (j=0; j<inH; j++) {
      for (i=0; i<inW; i++) {
         real[i] = c[i][j][0];
         imag[i] = c[i][j][1];
      }
      FFT(dir, inW, real, imag);
      for (i=0; i<inW; i++) {
         c[i][j][0] = real[i];
         c[i][j][1] = imag[i];
      }
   }
   delete []real;   delete []imag;

   /* Transform the columns */
   real = new double[inH];   imag = new double[inH];
   for (i=0; i<inW; i++) {
      for (j=0; j<inH; j++) {
         real[j] = c[i][j][0];
         imag[j] = c[i][j][1];
      }
      FFT(dir, inH, real, imag);
      for (j=0; j<inH; j++) {
         c[i][j][0] = real[j];
         c[i][j][1] = imag[j];
      }
   }
   free(real);
   free(imag);

   return 1;
}//FFT2D()

 // Prints the title & 2d array to the console & debugger output
void print2dArray(char str[100], int array[inD][inD]){
   cout << str; // Print the title
   //OutputDebugStringA(str); // Uncomment to print to debug output
   char buffer[100];
   for(int y=0;  y<inD;  y++){ // Print the array
      cout << "\n";
      //OutputDebugStringA("\n "); // Uncomment to print to debug output
      for(int x=0;  x<inD;  x++){
         cout << array[y][x] << "   "; 
         sprintf_s(buffer, "%i   ", array[y][x]);
         //OutputDebugStringA(buffer); // Uncomment to print to debug output
      }//for(x)
   }//for(y)
}//print2dArray()

 // Prints the title & 3d array to the console & debugger output
void printComplex2dArray(char str[100], double array[inD][inD][2]){
   cout << str; // Print the title
   //OutputDebugStringA(str); // Uncomment to print to debug output
   char buffer[100];
   for(int y=0;  y<inD;  y++){ // Print the array
      cout << "\n";
      //OutputDebugStringA("\n "); // Uncomment to print to debug output
      for(int x=0;  x<inD;  x++){
         cout << (int)array[y][x][0];  cout << ",";
         cout << (int)array[y][x][1];  cout << "      ";
         sprintf_s(buffer, "%i,", (int)array[y][x][0]);
         //OutputDebugStringA(buffer); // Uncomment to print to debug output
         sprintf_s(buffer, "%i   ", (int)array[y][x][1]);
         //OutputDebugStringA(buffer); // Uncomment to print to debug output
      }//for(x)
   }//for(y)
}//printComplex2dArray()

 // Cyclically shifts complex 2d array inRA by xOff & yOff to yield outRA.
void cyclicShiftComplex2dArray(double inRA[inD][inD][2], double outRA[inD][inD][2], 
                               int xOff, int yOff){
   for(int yOut=0, yIn=yOff;  yOut < inD;  yOut++, yIn++){
      yIn = yIn%inD;
      for(int xOut=0, xIn=xOff;  xOut < inD;  xOut++, xIn++){
         xIn = xIn%inD;
         outRA[yOut][xOut][0] = inRA[yIn][xIn][0];
         outRA[yOut][xOut][1] = inRA[yIn][xIn][1];
      }//for(xOut)
   }//for(yOut)
}//cyclicShiftComplex2dArray()
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the origin of the input and the output of the FFT is not in the middle of the image, it's in the top-left corner. You'd have to rotate around that pixel for this to work. The "centered" versions still don't have the origin the middle, it's in the pixel just right of the middle. Try again with an odd-sized image, un-center the image after rotation and before computing the FFT, and center again after calling the FFT and before rotating.

Comment: For even-sized images you'll have to put in a bit more effort to compute the rotation in the Fourier domain. The rotation happens around a point that is not the origin, and therefore there is an additional shift happening, which modifies the phase (the amplitude should be the same).

Comment: @Cris Thanks. I’ll experiment with odd-sized images first. But first please clarify:
I accept that the origin of the image & its FFT is at the top left corner pixel. 
(1) How do I rotate the image about the top left corner pixel? (2) What do you mean by, “un-center the image after rotation”?  
FFTs are periodic for both axes, with dimensions of powers of 2. (3) Would it suffice to just rotate the FFT about its center, and then cyclically shift the DC pixel back to the top left corner?